# Not getting token in localStorage

Tags: django, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the token from the localStorage but i'm getting error `401 unauthorized`.

**auth.service.ts** it's the services that handles the user login and logout service.

**account.service.ts** it's the service that handles the user registration part.

auth.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { apiHost } from '../aoi-host-url';
import { loginModel } from './login/login.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  static loginUrl: string = apiHost+'users/mylogin/';
  redirectUrl: string = "/dashboard";
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  login(data: loginModel): Observable<object> {
   /* This function makes the post call to API endpoint to login the user
    * with collected data from html form. The tap function sets the redirectUrl
    * to '/dashboard'
    */

    return this.http.post<object>(AuthService.loginUrl, data, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap( _ => {
        this.redirectUrl="/dashboard"
      })
    );
  }
  logout() {
    /*
     * On logging out we need to clear the localStorage and
     * redirect to login page.
     */
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    location.reload();
  }
  getToken(): string {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    return token ? token : ""

  }
  getHttpOptions(): any {
    /*
     * This function retrieves the token value from localStorge and returns it.
     */
    let httpOptionValue = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Token '+ localStorage.getItem('token')})
    };
    return httpOptionValue;
  }
}
```

account.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './account.model';
import { catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { apiHost } from '../aoi-host-url';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class AccountService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  static registerURL: string = apiHost+'users/register/';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };
  registerAccount(user: User): Observable<User> {
      /* This function makes the post call to API endpoint to register the user
       * with collected data from html form. The catchError function is currently
       * only logging the error and passing the error to where this observable is
       * subscribed
       */
      return this.http.post<User>(AccountService.registerURL, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError),
      );
  }
  private handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
      return throwError(errorResponse);
   }
}
```

Getting error  http://127.0.0.1:8000 401 (Unauthorized).